# Can I write this as a two-level list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I've got this bit:

```
for line in entireResult.split('\n'):
    print line.split(',')[0]
```

... and I feel like it can be list-comprehended, but I'm a bit too Friday-nighted. I tried something like:

```
[for l[0] in line.split(',') for line in entireResult('\n')]
```

but that didn't fly (line not defined). Is there a way to do this? Super-extra karma for answering before I finish coding my script with the boring loop codez.

Comment: `line.split(',')[0]` could be replaced by `line.partition(',')[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have one loop.

```
[line.split(',')[0] for line in entireResult.split('\n')]
```

Of course, you should do it as a generator if possible.

```
print '\n'.join(line.split(',')[0] for line in entireResult.split('\n'))
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for indulging my Friday-night lazyness!